# Objective-C: coping and deleting files (FileManager)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsfilemanager, fmdb

I'm working with a sqlite database application using FMDatabase.

I want to update a table of a database located in the main bundle

```
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:db_name];
```

with data in a Database located in the Documents Directory

```
NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *db_Path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:db_name];
```

I tried many times to execute an UPDATE query on the "default" database but it says it is locked. So I thought about coping it in Documents Directory with the name db_name_cp and working over it.

```
NSString *cpPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db_name_cp.sqlite"];
        success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:cpPath];
        if (success){
            //remove the existing one
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:cpPath error:&error];
        }
        //create the copy of the "main bundle" database
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:default_database.dbPath toPath:cpPath error:&error];
```

Then i tried to execute the UPDATE over the copied database but if I execute a SELECT over it, it is not updated and if I run the query on phpMyAdmin or SQLiteManager it updates the records.

Any idea? Maybe I'm wrong in coping them over the device directories.

Many thanks

Comment: You can't make changes to anything in the app, this obviously includes the app's mainBundle.

Comment: Yes I use to execute UPDATE queries on databases stored in doc directory and they work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make changes to anything in the app, this obviously includes the app's mainBundle, it is readonly and signed.

The Documents directory is fine, that it the correct directory to use.

If you need to merge then merge into the Documents directory DB. Or copy the bundle DB to the Documents directory on first launch and then merge into it.